# Close an Element on Touch Device Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which opens a div element on a touch screen device when the main nav menu link (.nav-landing > li) has been tapped. If the nav menu link is tapped for the second time the link becomes active and loads the page link. This all works fine but I can't figure out how to close the div element (.touch-device) if the user stays on the page and no longer needs to see the content within the div element.

(function ($) {

```
var landingLink = '.nav-landing > li';

// BROWSER WITH EITHER TOUCH EVENTS OR POINTER EVENTS RUNNING ON TOUCH-CAPABLE DEVICE
if (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0)) {

    // DISPLAY LANDING PAGE MEGA NAV ON TOUCH
    $(landingLink).live('touchstart', function (e) {
        'use strict';

        var link = $(this);
        var megaDiv = $(this).find('div');

        // REMOVE touch-device CLASS IF NAV LINK HASN'T BEEN TAPPED
        if (!megaDiv.hasClass('touch-device')) {
            $('.touch-device').removeClass('touch-device');
        }

        if (link.hasClass('hover')) {
            // SECOND TOUCH
            return true;
        } else {
            // FIRST TOUCH
            link.addClass('hover');
            megaDiv.addClass('touch-device');
            $(landingLink).not(this).removeClass('hover');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

    });

    $('.close-div').click(function () {
        //alert('clicked');
    });


} else { // STANDARD DESKTOP BROWSERS WITH MOUSE HOVER

    // DISPLAY LANDING PAGE MEGA NAV ON HOVER
    $(landingLink).has('div').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover').find('div').show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover').find('div').hide();
    });
}
```

})(jQuery);

I've also setup a JSFiddle to show the full example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bradford6/m5y72/)

Comment: How are you planning to let the user indicating that he doesn't need the div anymore? by tapping somewhere else? by adding an `x` button? .. oh wait, is that the question..?

Comment: I've added an X button with the class .close-div which can viewed on the JSFiddle link above.